Gitlab Runner submodule update fails when using GIT_STRATEGY: fetch if submodule moved between commits
First of all, the pipeline's GIT_STRATEGY: fetch is a requirement since the "clone" strategy is too costly. However, it doesn't seem to work when sequentially triggering pipelines on commits which have different git project structure. If a submodule moved, the runner simply won't be able to correctly update the submodules, probably because it is using git in a way that wasn't anticipating this scenario. Here's the case:
For clarity,

the older path for the submodule will be refered as path/to
the new path for the submodule will be refered as path/to/submodule

On the older commit
If the pipeline is run on the older commit (where the submodule was not nested) after the newer one, you get:
Updating/initializing submodules recursively with git depth set to 20...
Synchronizing submodule url for 'path/to'
fatal: not a git repository: path/to/../../.git/modules/path/to

I am guessing that the git project currently has an existing folder at .git/modules/path/submodule since the more recent version's submodule is located there. Hence, on the older version's pipeline, it tries to reuse that .git folder but fails because the path/to folder already exists and is not a git repositry (the expected repository is in fact in path/to/submodule!).
On the newer commit
If the pipeline is run on the newer commit (where the submodule was moved 1 folder deeper) after the old one, you get:
error: submodule git dir '/builds/my_repo/.git/modules/path/to/submodule' is inside git dir '/builds/my_repo/.git/modules/path/to'
fatal: refusing to create/use '/builds/my_repo/.git/modules/path/to/submodule' in another submodule's git dir
Failed to clone 'path/to/submodule'. Retry scheduled

This is a different effect to essentially the same issue. The runner tries to update the submodule in the path/to/submodule folder, but path/to already exists and is a valid repository, so git won't clone the submodule at that place.
Conclusion / Question
Is it really incompatible or am I missing something? Note that using the GIT_STRATEGY: clone "solves" the problem.
Would it be possible to not share the same .git folder cache between different commits' pipeline?
